# How to make a pause and play button function on a Javascript timer?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make the pause and play buttons function, but I'm not quite sure of the logic behind it. What I've tried before was to put `clearInterval` on pause button, but I don't really know how that works.Here is my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/fkhan698/pen/gJbjKN) for any help

```
// Countdown function. After timer hits 0, the 'counter turns red, and gong sounds through timerSound(), and options() runs
const countDown = ({minutes, seconds}) => {
    if (!minutes && seconds === '00'){
        const timer = document.getElementById('counter');

        options();
        timerSound();
        return;
}
// Sets timer. Subtracts the minutes set by 1
const myTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    if (seconds === '00'){
       minutes = minutes - 1;
     seconds = 60;
   }
// Subtracts the seconds
 seconds = seconds - 1;
 if (seconds < 10){
     seconds = '0' + seconds;
 }
 document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = minutes + " :";
 document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds;

   countDown({minutes, seconds});
}, 1000);
};
// Function that allows the CountDown to run
const initApp = () => {
countDown({
 minutes: 25,
 seconds: 01
    });
};

// Gets rid of the pausePlay class and displays the middlebuttons
const options = () => {
    const $pausePlay = document.getElementsByClassName("pausePlay");
    const $middleButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("middleButtons");

    for (var i = 0; i < $pausePlay.length; i++) {
        $pausePlay[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < $middleButtons.length; i++){
        $middleButtons[i].style.display = "block";
    }

    const fiveMinButton = document.getElementById('fiveMin');
    fiveMinButton.addEventListener('click', fiveMinBreak);

    const restartButton = document.getElementById('redo');
    redo.addEventListener('click', restartTimer);

    const endSession = document.getElementById('endSess');
    endSession.addEventListener('click', endSess);


}

//  Pause button
 const handleClickPauseButton = () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
    const $pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause");


 };
// Play button 
 const handleClickPlayButton = () => {

    const $playButton = document.getElementById("play");

 };
```

Comment: When you start your timer you use ```myTimer = setInterval (function, time);``` instead of ```setTimeout```. Then you can break the timer by calling ```clearInterval (myTimer)```.

Comment: Wait so what does that look like? Is it something like this ```const myTimer = setInterval((function,time) => {
    if (seconds === '00'){
       minutes = minutes - 1;
     seconds = 60;
   }```

Comment: I have already answered this question => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56318161/how-to-get-play-button-to-continue-timer-on-javascript/56319084#56319084

Comment: @MisterJojo so I tried to replace ```setTimeout``` with ```setInterval``` but when I start my timer is pretty much stops after 10 seconds. And when I call use the ```clearInterval(myTimer)``` it doesn't do anything

Comment: ?? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout

Comment: As  I said préviously( the other question on same subject) setTimeout and setInterval are not precise timer functions, when  you set their delay agument to 1000ms, the next call will always **append with more time than 1000ms, and could be 1020ms ,  1001ms, 1500ms...
 You can't use this delay to mesure real time**

Comment: @MisterJojo ohh okay I understand now